# Why am I always getting Segmentation faults when displaying my array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, fault

I've tried so much code trying to display my data in a histogram. I've been stuck on this problem for two days now, data crawling the internet and such to find an answer but they usually talk about pointers and ect. while this is much more basic. I've tried an actual histogram that displayed the same error but for the sake of keeping it simple I choose to post this one.

This is the description of the program from The C Programming language:
"Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of the words in its input. "
I'm doing it horizontally then I will do it vertically. Although, in this example I am just trying to display the number, obviously.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXIMUM 99


main()
{
int i, c, j, lenOfWord[MAXIMUM], charCount;

for (i = 0; i < MAXIMUM; i++)
    lenOfWord[i] = 0;


printf("Starting program, please type then ctrl+d\n");



while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ') {
        //new word
        ++lenOfWord[charCount];
        charCount = 0;
    }
    else
        //inword
        ++charCount;
}

printf("\n Displaying now... \n");


for (j = 0; j <= MAXIMUM; j++)
    printf("%d: %d", j, lenOfWord[j]); 


}
```

output:

```
 JohnJackson@linux-72db:~/Desktop> gcc c.c -o c
 JohnJackson@linux-72db:~/Desktop> ./c
 Starting program, please type then ctrl+d
 Hello my name is john jacksonSegmentation fault
```

*Segmentation fault on the end is what i get when I do EOF (ctrl+D)

Additional information: GCC compiler from terminal in openSUSE linux

Thanks so much, I'm trying to learn C but I've hit alot of road blocks like these, I'm getting frustrated.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use the debugger (`gdb`)

Comment: `j >= MAXIMUM`? That'll terminate your loop on the first iteration. the second clause of a `for()` is the loop termination condition. As long as the condition evaluates to "true", the loop continues executing. You've basically setting up your loops to fail, since `0 >= 99` is false right off the bat.

Comment: charCount is never initialized, and you're trying to access lenOfWord[charCount]

Comment: sorry everyone, I fixed the for error, but I am getting the same segmentation error

Comment: @user275564 Which of the errors did you fix - why not update the question with what's currently not working?

Comment: The uninitialized `charCount` is your immediate problem, I believe. Fix that and you'll run into more.

Comment: The underlying reason that you're having problems is that you're failing to appreciate that programming requires *precision*. Read over your program *carefully* to see if what you're doing makes sense and is accurate.

Comment: I have updated the program. The problem has been solved. It was the uninitialized variable charCount. I found that this has been the same error throughout and all my programs, I have been forgeting to initialize my variables.  Thanks everyone. Lesson learned. Jim, I will take more time to be precise and accurate. Thank you everyone.

Comment: As one more general hint, especially for any novice programmer: always use those `{}` for ifs and loops, even if there is one statement. It's just too easy to make a mistake. So just put them there to eliminate a few possible issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is

```
++lenOfWord[charCount];
        charCount = 0;
```

You have not initialized `charCount` to `0` before using it. Initialize it to 0 first before the loop

```
charCount = 0;

while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
```

And assigning `charCount` to `0` in loop is of no use. Remove it.

You have to check one more thing. Since the array size is `MAXIMUM`. So You have to put a check that `charCount` does not exceed `MAXIMUM`. Otherwise, it will again give `segmentation fault`.

Another problem is in the for loop condition. Instead of

```
for (i = 0; i < MAXIMUM; i++)
```

change it to

```
for (i = 0; i < MAXIMUM; i++)
```

And

Instead of

```
for (j = 0; j >= MAXIMUM; j++)
```

to

```
for (j = 0; j < MAXIMUM; j++)
```

Otherwise you won't get any output.

Comment: I think you are correct, thank you so much. Although, I believe that setting the charCount back to 0 after a space is essential to the program. The char Count after a space is 0.

Comment: what is the difference between the first two for statements in your example?

Answer (score 0):

Your `charCount` variable is not initialized

Comment: Thank you sir/mam, problem solved. I think this was the problem in my last versions of the program. LESSON LEARNED!